# Comparison "or" conditional

Tags: templating, conditional

I'm trying to use a conditional to do something if the first segment matches This *or* That. But I'm unable to come up with the right operator for the "or"

```
{% elseif craft.request.firstSegment == 'This' || 'That' %}
```

What's the proper operator here? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want:

```
{% if craft.request.firstSegment == 'This' or craft.request.firstSegment == 'That' %}
```

or this would work:

```
{% if craft.request.firstSegment in ['This', 'That'] %}
```